# Solar system galactic velocity vector relative to ecliptic plane

Tags: orbital-mechanics, velocity, ecliptic-plane, galactic

The Solar system moves through the Milky Way galaxy with velocity of [230 km/s](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_year).
The ecliptic plane is located ~60 degrees with relation to the galaxy plane, according to [this source](https://medium.com/starts-with-a-bang/ask-ethan-37-the-earths-motion-through-the-galaxy-a4787fd46d4b).
The page also shows animated gif of the solar system motion through the galaxy (marked with "Image credit: Rhys Taylor), in which the galactical motion appears to be southwards (relative to the ecliptic plane).
[Direct link to the gif](https://miro.medium.com/max/2400/1*XI-H2Vjx-I5VRq844sPA6g.gif)

On the contrary, the following image (borrowed from [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33821) on Astronomy SE) indicates solar system moves northwards relative to ecliptic plane:
[image]

*Question*: If we wanted to send a probe in prograde galactical motion of the solar system, within the galaxy plane, would we need to direct it southwards or northwards relative to the ecliptic plane?